# Translate names or not

Tags: oop, unix, structure

This is just a general design question. I'm designing a small app which needs to store files in a hierarchical fashion 
ex:

```
dept/group/user1/file#1
dept/group5/user2/file#7
```

The usernames can have any characters like '/', '@' too.

Would it be wise to use the username as the dir name or should I maintain a mapping file under each group which maps each username to a simplified generic dirname i.e

```
user1=dir1
user7=dir7
```

Comment: Having directories with the `/` character in their name is not possible in UNIX. Can you guess why? With this in mind, it wouldn't be possible to represent each user as a directory named after their username. Maybe you could use a hash sum of their username. Either that or change the requirement for usernames.

Comment: @htor yes / would make it look like a dir, hash sum is a great idea!! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some people have suggested hashing your usernames, this is both opaque to inspection (so you can't tell by examining the filesystem what the usernames that correspond to the directories are) and non-reversible (so neither human system administrators nor software can ever enumerate the usernames by consulting the filesystem). Therefore it may or may not work for you.

I suggest encoding the usernames. By inspiring myself from the 2 main content encodings used in [MIME](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), may I suggest either **quoted-printable** or **base64**?

- With **[quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)**, you can encode all the "unusual" bytes in the username while leaving most of the printable characters as-is. This way, it is still fairly obvious what the usernames are when examining the directory with `ls`. You should encode at least all control characters (bytes with values between 0 and 31 as well as 127), **=**, **/**, and all chararters that are special to the shell (like space, quotes, **$**, **#**, etc...). The disadvantage of quoted-printable is that if the usernames are expected to contain a lot of these unusual characters, the filenames can become very long: each encoded sequence takes 3 bytes.
- **[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)** is an encoding that will be more compact than quoted-printable in case the usernames might contain a lot of characters that need encoding, but it is not immediately readable to humans, so an `ls` of your directory doesn't look very clear. Note that you have to modify the last character of standard base64, for example by changing the last character of the alphabet from **/** to **-** [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Filenames) because otherwise the encoded strings can contain **/**.